# URL of Site Visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Im using `Visual Studio 2015` & `ASP .NET WebForms` and cannot see the full url of my site.

[image]

Where's the property that allows the site to show in which page im on?

Regards!

Comment: Are you using web forms, or MVC?

Comment: Web forms, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

localhost:22696 is equivalent to localhost:22696/default.aspx. I IIS u can define which default page to show. Like IIS, IIS express (which run on vs debug) it treats localhost:22696 as localhost:22696/default.asx. you can try localhost:22696/default.asx that returns same page like localhost:22696.

Comment: Other developers here using VS 2015 are seeing the actual URL, so this answer is not usefull. Sorry.